# Ajax asynchronous not returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm stuck at this point, could anyone help me out on this piece of code!!...Its a asynchronous point at which it returns before getting the value tried to make `async: false` but could not get the return value.

```
function Routing(){
    var from= document.getElementById("from").value;
    var to =document.getElementById("to").value;

    var fromcoordinates=coordinates(from);
    var tocoordinates=coordinates(to);

    console.log(fromcoordinates);
}
function coordinates(values){
 var cords;
    $.ajax({
         url: 'https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json',
         type: 'GET',  
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         async : false,
         jsonp: 'jsoncallback',

         data: {
           searchtext: values,
           gen: '9',
           apiKey: 's_WF6U2g60ucHbmnYIyuieeUWnkT0jshGf4mD33kpwI'
         },
         success: function (data) {

          var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          cords=[x.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude, x.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude];
          console.log(cords);
         }

       });
    console.log(cords);
    return cords;
      }
```

Comment: Can you post the values of "values"?

Comment: Those are location names which would be converted into coordinates when coordinates method is called!

Comment: Why don`t you just return cords inside the success function, it should work fine.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I don't think returning it in success will help.

Comment: I have run the code and it was returning the result successfully.

Comment: tried but it isnt returning to the web page as @MattU said!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `success` callback is fired later, after the function executes and returns `cords`. Instead, you can wrap `coordinates` in a promise, then use `Promise.all`:

```js
function Routing(){
    var from= document.getElementById("from").value;
    var to =document.getElementById("to").value;

    var fromcoordinates=coordinates(from);
    var tocoordinates=coordinates(to);

    Promise.all([fromcoordinates, tocoordinates]).then(values => {
        // values[0] = from
        // values[1] = to
        console.log(values[0]);
        console.log(values[1]);
    });
}

function coordinates(values) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
         url: 'https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json',
         type: 'GET',  
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         async : false,
         jsonp: 'jsoncallback',

         data: {
           searchtext: values,
           gen: '9',
           apiKey: 's_WF6U2g60ucHbmnYIyuieeUWnkT0jshGf4mD33kpwI'
         },
         success: function (data) {

          var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          // Resolve the promise with the coordinates
          resolve([x.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude, x.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude]);
         }

       });
    });
}
```

Comment: Matt U can i keep the returned values in a variables because i want to use the values further!

Comment: You can use async/await syntax which will make it much cleaner, if that syntax is available to you (e.g. supported). See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function If that's not available, it'll be difficult without passing callbacks or returning `Promise` objects everywhere you need it.